# ContentControl two way binding within DataTemplate not working?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate, contentcontrol

I've setup a reusable datatemplate "DataGridCheckBoxEdit" for a datagrid column. Binding to it one way works like a charm through ContentControl. Binding directly works two way correctly. However, binding two way within that DataTemplate, from a ContentControl just won't work.

Here are the snippets:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=IsMadeAvailable, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource     DataGridCheckBoxEdit}" />
</DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

and the reusable template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataGridCheckBoxEdit">
<CheckBox Name="CheckBoxControl" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=DataContext.Content, Mode=TwoWay, BindsDirectlyToSource=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="8,4,2,2" />
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
<Trigger SourceName="CheckBoxControl" Property="IsVisible" Value="True">
<Setter TargetName="CheckBoxControl" Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=CheckBoxControl}"/>
</Trigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

As I said, one way binding works like a charm...but getting the data back to the property doesn't.

Of course, putting it without being reusable:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<CheckBox Name="GasIsAvailableCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsMadeAvailable, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="8,4,2,2" />
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
<Trigger SourceName="GasIsAvailableCheckBox" Property="IsVisible" Value="True">
<Setter TargetName="GasIsAvailableCheckBox" Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=GasIsAvailableCheckBox}"/>
</Trigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

also works great, and works two-way.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Vladan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your binding is just broken (see the output window of Visual Studio for the respective errors), you do not want to bind to `DataContext.Content` but just `Content`, the `DataContext` would be the object in that row instead of the `ContentControl` itself.

Change that in the binding path of the reusable template and it will work. You also set a lot of properties to values they already have by default, this would be the minimal version:

```
{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}}
```